# Find original name of a message obtained by RegisterWindowMessage Windows API

Tags: c++, winapi

While debugging the application in an attempt to improve performance, I found that it loses time in processing a message that is greater then 0xC000. This is obviously a message created by the `RegisterWindowMessage` API. However, the application uses more than two hundreds such messages; is there a way to find the original name of the message by its numerical value?

The `GetAtomName` and `GlobalGetAtomName` fail with

> ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

error.

Comment: Find all the calls to RegisterWindowMessage

Comment: You could try `GetClipboardFormatName`, since although it's not documented as such it appears that `RegisterWindowMessage` and `RegisterClipboardFormat` are actually the same function.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: `RegisterWindowMessage()` and `RegisterClipboardFormat()` are NOT the same function. They are not even related to each other, except for the fact that they *currently* share an atom table, but that is not contractual and should not be relied on

Comment: @RemyLebeau Agreed but if it's for a temporary in-house debugging issue then it can't really hurt...

Comment: @RemyLebeau - *are NOT the same function.* - currently (xp-win10) it is the exactly *same* function. both names resolved to the same address

Comment: @RbMm: perhaps, but that is still an implementation detail that can be changed in the future

Comment: @RemyLebeau - yes. but i only clarified that this 2 names resolved to the same function (if say call GetProcAddress for both)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## There is no *official* API to get the name of a registered window message.

That being said, `RegisterWindowMessage()` and `RegisterClipboardFormat()` happen to *currently* share a single atom table (along with a few other API functions), so in *current* version of Windows, you can use [`GetClipboardFormatName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649040.aspx) to get the name of a registered window message.

This is described on Raymond Chen's blog on MSDN:

[How can I investigate the possibility of a lot of leaked window classes (RegisterClass)?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171006-00/?p=97147)

> It so happens that in current versions of Windows, registered class names, **registered clipboard format names, and registered window message names all come from the same atom table**. I wish to reiterate that this is **an implementation detail** which can change at any time, so don't take any dependencies on this. I provide this information for diagnostic purposes, which is what we have here.
>
> The customer can do this once they encounter the problem:
>
> ```
> Foreach atom in (0xC000 .. 0xFFFF)
>   If (GetClipboardFormatName(atom, buffer, bufferSize))
>     Print buffer
> ```
>
> This will print out the names of all the classes, **clipboard formats, and registered window messages**. There is room in the atom table for 16,384 atoms, and in practice there aren't more than a hundred or so, so if you see more than 15,000 entries, that's a really good sign that you're leaking classes.

[Some other places atoms (and the magical 0xC000) arise](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080430-00/?p=22523)

> I'll start with registered window messages, created by the RegisterWindowMessage function. **These are not officially atoms**; they are just integers that happen to lie in the range 0xC000 to 0xFFFF, just like atoms. But yeah, **internally, they're atoms**. Of course, you shouldn't rely on it since it's not contractual. Think of it as a fantastic coincidence.
>
> Registered clipboard formats created by the RegisterClipboardFormat message are also **not officially atoms**; they're just UINTs. The numeric range for registered clipboard formats isn't even specified; that they hang out in the 0xC000 range is just **an implementation detail**. Someday, registered clipboard formats may have values like 0x1234, who knows.

So, as I said, there is currently **NO OFFICIAL API** to get the name of a registered window message, but you can *currently* get around that by treating a registered window message the same as a registered clipboard format.  But using `GetClipboardFormatName()` in this manner *MAY* break in the future if the implementation of `RegisterWindowMessage()` ever changes.

Comment: *currently share a single atom table* simply because it the same function currently

Comment: Key phrase in context of this Q&A: *"I provide this information for diagnostic purposes"*. It's enough to point out, that the concepts here are based on implementation details. Repeating it doesn't help any. A developer knows, what an implementation detail is. Everyone else will just ignore it the seventh time around. *"This is documented on Raymond Chen's MSDN blog"* should probably also be reworded. Even if literally correct, the terms *"documented"* and *"MSDN"* in the same sentence do suggest some sort of official nature.

Comment: @Remy, Thank you very much! It helped me a lot. I need this only for debugging and profiling, it will not remain in the release code.