# How Log Message Events by ApplicationEvents in delphi?

Tags: list, delphi, message

I can get events HexCode by onMessage event of applicationEvents component.
By this code:

```
MessagesList.Items.Add(IntToStr(MSG.message));
```

But I want get MessageText and add it into ListBox. For example when user pressed LeftMouseButton add "WM_LBUTTONDOWN" in ListBox.

I want List and Log All of Events handled in `form.(onclick,onmousedown,onmouseup,onmousemove,....)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide more info.

Answer (score 1):

You have to construct your own lookup table for this.  There is no built-in facility that will convert a message ID to a string representing the message's name.

Comment: For messages in the `0xC000..0xFFFF` range, you can [*currently* use `GetClipboardFormatName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49543193/65863) to get its name, at least (MAY change in the future, though!)