# How do I turn a list argument to a macro into a heavily modified but quoted list as a result?

Tags: macros, lisp

How do I turn a list argument to a macro into a heavily modified but quoted list as a result?

I translated into Lisp John Foster's example for converting win32 WM_* messages into helpful text.
[Convert Windows Message IDs to Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252398/convert-windows-message-ids-to-text)

I needed to define the win32 constants and a macro seemed perfect for calling (defconstant WM_PAINT 15) and registering WM_PAINT and "WM_PAINT" automatically.

**Working Test Code:**

```
(defmacro def-windows-message (&rest rest )
    "Converts a list of windows messages into defconstant and a string lookup in GetMessageText."
    `(block nil 
        ,@(loop for pair in rest collect
            `(defconstant ,(car pair) ,(cadr pair)))
        (defparameter *windows-message-lookup* #(
            ,@(loop for pair in rest collect (cons (cadr pair) (string (car pair) )))
        ))
        (defun GetMessageText (id) 
            (destructuring-bind (index text)
                (msgid_to_index id *windows-message-lookup* 0 (length *windows-message-lookup*))
                (if (= index -1)
                    (format nil "(WM_? ~a)" id)
                    ; else
                    text)))
        (defun msgid_to_index (target_id array min_idx max_idx)
            (let* ( (cur_idx (floor (/ (+ max_idx min_idx) 2)))
                    (cur_pair (aref array cur_idx))
                    (cur_id (car cur_pair))
                    (cur_text (cdr cur_pair)))
                (cond
                    ((= target_id cur_id) (list cur_idx cur_text))
                    ((> target_id cur_id) 
                        (if (= cur_idx min_idx)
                            '(-1 nil)
                            ; else
                            (msgid_to_index target_id array cur_idx max_idx)))
                    ((< target_id cur_id) 
                        (if (= cur_idx max_idx)
                            '(-1 nil)
                            ;else
                            (msgid_to_index target_id array min_idx cur_idx)))
                )
            )
        )
    ))

; Test it!
(def-windows-message
    (WM_NULL 0)
    (WM_CREATE 1))
(format t "~a~%" (GetMessageText 0))
(format t "~a~%" (GetMessageText 1))
(format t "~a~%" (GetMessageText -1))
(format t "~a~%" (GetMessageText 99))
```

**Working Output:**

```
C:\lisphack>clisp test_macro_long_list.lisp
WM_NULL
WM_CREATE
(WM_? -1)
(WM_? 99)
```

Excellent.  That's exactly what I want.

However, when I add 240 more windows messages to the list, it fails.

**Long List Failure Output**: `*** - VALUES-LIST: too many return values`

This message means that too many function parameters are being passed to the #() function.

I finally just create the array empty and then loop through the list inserting each element into teh array.

**Working but gross snippet:**

```
(defparameter *windows-message-looup* (make-array ,(length rest) :initial-element '(-1 Nil)))
    ,@(loop for pair in rest for idx from 0 collect `(setf (aref *windows-message-lookup* ,idx) (cons ,(cadr pair) ,(string (car pair) ))))
```

What I really want is to convert the &rest list into the proper form, then send that list into the array constructor as initial values:

**Elegant but flawed**

```
(defparameter *windows-message-lookup* (make-array ,(length rest) 
    ,@(loop for pair in rest collect (cons (cadr pair) (string (car pair) )))
```

**Error:** `*** - EVAL: 0 is not a function name; try using a symbol instead`
I think that means the eventual parameter to `make-array` is being executed instead of quoted as an initializer.

I need one extra quote on the resulting list.
**One More Quote**

```
(defparameter *windows-message-lookup* (make-array ,(length rest) 
    `,@(loop for pair in rest collect ,(cons (cadr pair) (string (car pair) )))))
```

**Error:** `*** - READ: the syntax` ,@form is invalid`

I've tried a few variations adding extra backquotes or moving the parenthesis around, but they result in a list of my list or the argument pairs executing instead of reading.

[EDITED]
Thank-you.  This looks better than what I was attempting.  For my education, what's the correct form of this macro?

```
(defmacro def-windows-message (&rest rest )
    `(defparameter *windows-message-lookup* 
        (make-array 
            ,(length rest) 
            `(,@(loop for pair in rest collect ,(cons (cadr pair) (string (car pair) )))))))
```

For an input of `(def-windows-message '((onefish 1) (twofish 2) .. ))`
I want `(make-array 999 '( (onefish "onefish") (twofish "twofish") ... ))` as the result.

I'm having trouble with correctly quoting the resulting list and still processing it in the macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to understand what this macro was doing but gave up when I realised it's using binary search on an array to find the message.  This is why translating C into Lisp is almost never the right answer.

I am not completely sure but I think you probably want this:

```
(defvar *windows-message-lookup*
  ;; Unless you have vast numbers of messages (thousands) and/or the
  ;; code is very performance sensitive, this could as well be an
  ;; alist
  (make-hash-table))

(defmacro def-windows-messages (&body messages)
  "Define a bunch of windows messages, each message is (name id)"
  `(progn
    ,@(loop for (name id) in messages
            collect `(defconstant ,name ,id)
            collect `(setf (gethash ,id *windows-message-lookup*)
                           (string ',name)))
    (values)))

(defun get-message-text (id) 
  "Return the text associated with ID and T if it's found, or a string
saying it's not found and NIL if it's not found."
  (multiple-value-bind (text foundp)
      (gethash id *windows-message-lookup*)
    (values (if foundp text (format nil (format nil "(WM_? ~a)" id)))
            foundp)))
```

And now:

```
> (def-windows-messages
    (WM_NULL 0)
    (WM_CREATE 1))

> (get-message-text 0)
"WM_NULL"
t

> (get-message-text 1)
"WM_CREATE"
t

> (get-message-text -1)
"(WM_? -1)"
nil

> (get-message-text 99)
"(WM_? 99)"
nil
```

Note that as the code now is (it was previously slightly different) it would work to say

```
(defconstant some-id 12)
(define-windows-messages
  (WM_FOO some-id))
```

---

As an example of the quoting problems which were part of the original macro, here is a macro called `define-message-array` which can be used to define arrays of messages in a similar way to the original macro.  It differs from the original macro in that you can specify the name of the array.

```
(defmacro define-message-array (name &body from)
  `(defparameter ,name
     (make-array ,(length from) 
                 :initial-contents
                 '(,@(loop for (n v) in from
                           collect (cons v (string n)))))))
```

Note that there is no nested backquoting here: you don't often need that.

With this, then

```
(define-message-array *foo*
  (x 1)
  (y 2))
```

expands to

```
(defparameter *foo*
  (make-array 2 :initial-contents '((1 . "X") (2 . "Y"))))
```

Comment: Thank-you.  This looks better than what I was attempting.

Comment: For my education, I added an EDIT to the bottom of the question.  Thank-you.

Comment: I've added an example of how to do that, although I think it might be better done as a separate question (not sure though).

Comment: Thank-you very much!